# Find solutions of the inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, logarithms

> Find all real values of $x$ satisfying the inequality: $x^{\log_3
>  (x+4)} \lt 3^5$.

Comment: Can you show as your work?

Comment: I'm a final year student at the Da Nang University of Education. I major in mathematics.

Comment: Great, I'm still curious about what you did to solve it so far.

Comment: I confess that I haven't solved this problem. I have a sister who is studying 12, and she needs help. I'm regret that I don't remember about it. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: take the logarithm w.r.t to $3$ on both sides of the inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Take base 3 logarithms on both sides. Sign does not change as function is increasing:-
$$(\log_3x)(\log_3(x+4))<5$$

The function $(\log_3x)(\log_3(x+4))$ is increasing. Solving $(\log_3x)(\log_3(x+4))=5$ gives $x\approx9.9024$ (from [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log3(x)*log3(x%2B4)%3D5))

So answer would be $x<9.9024$

Answer (score -4):

We need to solve $f(x)<5$, where $f(x)=\log_3x\log_3(x+4)$.

But $f$ is an increasing function on $[1,+\infty)$ and all $0<x<1$ are solutions.

Thus, the answer is $(0,x_0)$, where $x_0$ is a root of the equation $f(x)=5$:

$x_0=9.9024...$

Comment: How about $x=-1$?

Comment: @Eugen Covaci $\log_3(-1)$ does not exist.

Comment: Check the initial inequality, there is no $\log_3(-1)$ there.

Comment: By the definition then x > 0.

Comment: @Eugen Covaci If we have $x^{h(x)}$ so should be $x>0$ at least.

Comment: $(-1)^1 \lt 3^5$ what is incorrect about this?

Comment: @Eugen Covaci $(-1)^1<3^5$ it's all right, but $(-1.5)^{\log_{3}2.5}<5$ is wrong. If you see $x^{h(x)}$ so by definition $x>0$ at least. You have to learn it

Comment: @Eugen Covaci Take calculator and try to calculate $(-1.5)^{\log_{3}2.5}$. What do you get?